# can't define a single object in header accross several DLL

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am using VS2010 on a solution with 2 DLLS and I'm trying to define a global variable to be used across both DLLS.

I have the following code:

```
header.h
        namespace A
        {   
            extern DLL_A int myInt;
        }
```

in a a.cpp file in DLL A:

```
#include "header.h"
using namespace A;

DLL_A int A::myInt = 5; //initialisation
```

in another b.cpp file in DLL A:

```
#include "header.h"
using namespace A;
//use myInt for computations in some method, eg myInt++; etc
```

DLL_A is defined as the usual:

```
#ifdef SOME_DEFINE
#       define DLL_A __declspec(dllexport)
#   else
#       define DLL_A __declspec(dllimport)
#   endif
```

However what happens is that while debugging in b.cpp, I see in the watch window that &A::myInt and &myInt are different, which means that an (unknown) "myInt" variable is used for computations, while A::myInt is correctly initialized to 5.

can someone explain to me what is going on and how to fix this? I don't see how it's possible to link properly, because I have 2 different extern variables that are created and I only initialise one.

edit :

if I change

```
DLL_A int A::myInt = 5; //initialisation
```

for

```
DLL_A int myInt = 5; //initialisation
```

it won't link

thanks

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question but it sounds like you're trying to `extern` an `int` across two DLLs. That's not possible unless you put it in a shared data segment. [See MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h90dkhs0(v=vs.90).aspx) for details.

Comment: yes that's what I want to do
are you sure it's impossible? Anyway my test case only uses one DLL and it's already not working within a single DLL

Comment: Ok, check the MSDN link in my previous comment, you can do it with a shared data segment.

Comment: @RogerRowland: That's nonsense. A shared data segment is shared across processes. `dllexport/dllimport` is the correct way to share across DLL boundaries within a single process.

Comment: @MSalters "nonsense"? That's harsh. The OP didn't mention anything about a single process did he?

Comment: Using __declspec on a variable is a [supported scenario](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/90530).  It is entirely unclear why you are having a problem.  Could be something silly like using a stale DLL.

Comment: @HansPassant my original understanding is that the OP has two DLLs being used by one (or more) processes, and he wants to share data *between* the DLLs (which are otherwise unrelated). Maybe OP can clarify the problem?

Comment: @RogerRowland: He talks about a global variable. That unambiguously means "process-wide" in C++.

Comment: @MSalters I see what you mean but only the OP can say for sure. If he's doing what I *think* he's doing, it would explain the problem he's seeing, wouldn't it? I think he has an application that links to two DLLs and he wants those DLLs to define some shared data between them (i.e. not between the DLL and the exe). I think we need clarification on the problem if your answer is not helpful.

Comment: @Roger Rowland I actually have a single process sorry..., so I don't think I need to use data segment. I checked the codebase and there are other instances of sharing an int accross dll the same way I am doing. sorry I wasn't clear

Comment: No problem, I could happily debate with the other users in the meantime ;-) The main thing is that you get your question answered, which I see @MSalters has done, which is excellent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say " I see in the watch window that &A::myInt and &myInt are different, which means that an (unknown) "myInt" variable is used for computations".

That there is exactly your problem. `using namespace A;` means that an unqualified name such a `myInt` will be looked up in `A` only *after* the lookup has failed in the current (i.e. global) namespace. But the debugger shows that `::myInt` exist. Therefore, `myInt` means `::myInt`, the first lookup succeeds, and no second lookup is done for `::A::myInt`.

Comment: ok I see!
But where in the code I posted do I define ::myInt ?